# Can I get Bokeh to NOT generate javascript all on one line?

Tags: bokeh

I've never worked with Bokeh before, so apologies if this question doesn't make sense.  I have a plot that someone else generated using Bokeh and it has a huge JSON object (docs_json) that is all on the same line.  I need to import this plot into a WordPress site which has a line length limit.  Is there any way I can get Bokeh to generate that JSON in a prettified form rather than squishing the whole thing onto one line?

I'm in a situation where I'm working with 100s of plots being generated continuously, so I'd prefer not to have to manually touch each plot after it is generated.

Comment: Try running the output through a [JSON Beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I am looking for a solution that doesn't require me to manually touch the file after it is generated.

Comment: I admit I'm not familiar with bokeh but a brief look at the documentation shows that there's an optional `pretty` parameter which would do what you want: [serialize_json](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/json_encoder.html)

Comment: Thanks, @CoreyOgburn- that looks really promising as well as the answer below.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: `serialize_json` is a couple of levels below APIs that general users typically use. It's an option, but would involve more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the simplest way is to use the `BOKEH_PRETTY` environment variable when running any Bokeh code, e.g.

```
BOKEH_PRETTY=true python iris.py
```

Results in HTML output with embedded JSON that looks like:

```html
<script type="application/json" id="4074acb8-0b70-4591-8d43-99873a9e1bc4">
  {
    "9d745210-1f6a-4c22-b8ca-c3d2b3829a8f": {
      "roots": {
        "references": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "bottom_units": "screen",
              "fill_alpha": {
                "value": 0.5
              },

              ...

        ],
        "root_ids": [
          "ce2c1a38-e3e5-4155-9a80-6860dc284dbc"
        ]
      },
      "title": "Bokeh Application",
      "version": "0.12.15dev1"
    }
  }
</script>
```

All of Bokeh's settings and their associated environment variables are documented in the reference guide:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/settings.html

Comment: Oh, man- this will save me so much time.  Thank you so much!!